# Assign value to variable from database content in Django

Tags: android, python, django, variables

Hi i have a function which fetches the field value which can have one value out of total four values from database on the base of which i need to display some data according to value

```
update_grp = User_Groups.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    showopen = update_grp.profilegroup
    if showopen == "trendy":
      slidercategory = Category.objects.get(id = 65)
    elif showopen == "Classic":
      slidercategory = Category.objects.get(id = 63)
    elif showopen == "Glam":
      slidercategory = Category.objects.get(id = 81)
    elif showopen == "Bohemian":
      slidercategory = Category.objects.get(id = 62)
    sliderproduct = slidercategory.product_set.all()
```

but i got the following error

```
local variable 'slidercategory' referenced before assignment
```

please suggest where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showopen` variable isn't in the four options provided by your code. If you don't have a debugger to see what the variable actually is, then add some print statements to your code that print the variable to the console.

```
update_grp = User_Groups.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    showopen = update_grp.profilegroup
    print showopen
    #..
```

Comment: thanks for the reply yes you was right showopen variable isn't in the four options but now i am able to get its value and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an 'else' clause so the interpretator sees there could be a case where 'slidercategory' isn't available within the scope of your function (where non of the if statements are matched).

Either add an else clause or assign sliderproduct = 'somedefaultvalue' at the top of your function, another solution would be to move the return bar into the if clauses their scopes, which would result in a None being returned when none of the ifs are matched.

```
>>> def test(foo):
...     if foo == 2:
...        bar = 'hello'
...     elif foo == 3:
...        bar = 'goodbye'
...     return bar
>>> test(2)
>>> 'hello'
>>> test(1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: That's not the case with my interpreter. I did a quick test assigning values with `if True:` along with `elif False:` (no else), and my function worked fine.

Comment: How is 'if True' comparing an assigned value? The error thrown 'local variable 'slidercategory' referenced before assignment' is explicitly stating the problem..

Comment: no really, I've run your code above in my python 2.7.2 and it runs fine - test(2) returns 'hello'.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my console to my answer - I wouldn't believe me either :)

Comment: Ofcourse it works like that, but that's not the problem is it? You're solving the problem from the input value's point of view, that's like saying, 'make sure the entered value is correct and your function will work as expected'. I am pointing out the scope will always break if you don't actually check the input's value.

Comment: I understand. I think you're making a good point. I would be interested to know where you ran code you've included in your answer?